# How to send a text from an input using twilio and svelte?

Tags: api, post, twilio, twilio-api

I see a lot of docs for this but nothing javascript. My lack of knowledge is coming into play here, so forgive me. I want to send a simple text to a phone number that is typed into an input. I have a serverless function set up but i don't know how to pass in the phone number to it, beyond that I have tried to write a post request to it but I must be way off. Is what I am doing possible?

```
let phoneNumber;

const handleSendText = () => {
    fetch("https://svelte-service-xxxx.twil.io/sms", {
      method: "post",
      body: "This is a test",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      to: JSON.stringify(phoneNumber),
      from: "+xxxxxxxxxxx",
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("failed");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="phone number" />
 <button on:click={handleSendText}>Send</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [bind the value of the `<input>` to a variable in your script](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/text-inputs).

```html
<script>
let phoneNumber = "";

const handleSendText = () => { // we'll come back to this };
</script>

<input type="text" placeholder="phone number" bind:value={phoneNumber} />
<button on:click={handleSendText}>Send</button>
```

That makes it so that when you change the value in the input it updates the `phoneNumber` variable.

Now, in your `handleSendText` function you need to send all the parameters within the `body` of the request. Note, in the following code how the `body` contains all the parameters you want to send in one JSON stringified object.

```js
const handleSendText = () => {
  fetch("https://svelte-service-9106.twil.io/sms", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      to: phoneNumber,
      from: "+18035298025"
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("failed");
    } else {
      console.log("Success!");
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

Then, in your Twilio function you will be able to access the parameters you send in the `event` object. In this case, you will have `event.to` and `event.from`.